# How do I load a dynamic jquery ui dialog from URL?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a page which has a series of dynamic jquery ui dialogs which have different id's. For example:

```
<div id="message-1">
content
</div>

<div id="message-2">
content
</div>
```

I want some code that can launch the appropriate dialog box based on URL.

For example, if the url was http://url.com/#message-2 it would open only the appropriate dialog box.

I've been trying to use code like the following as a basis to start from, but it clearly isn't a solution.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('#message') != -1) {
            $('.dialog').dialog('open');
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I notice you tagged this with PHP too - can you output your js using PHP to obtain the message id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
    $(window.location.hash).dialog('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location.hash to get the #message-part of the url.

```
if(window.location.hash == '#message-1') {
            $('.message-1').dialog('open');
}
```

This code works with #message-1, #message-2 ... #message-n

```
if(window.location.hash != '') {
            $('.' + window.location.hash).dialog('open');
}
```

Note: You should probably validate input but i didn't since it's an example

Comment: I could do with making it dynamic though.

So I don't have to repeat that line and instead whatever the number is after the message- part of the string bit becomes a variable which is used to invoke the correct dialog window.

In pseudo code:

if url == '#message-'
get number after #message and set to variable
run $('.message-').dialog('open'); with the variable appended

Hopefully I'm explaining myself correctly here.

Comment: I'm not sure if I undestood your question. If you're trying to extract the id I would go for an regex: var msgId = window.location.hash.replace(/^#message-([0-9]+)$/, '$1')